# JTOpen - Set user password as expired

Tags: java, jtopen

One of my Java applications that comunicates with an AS400 server using JTOpen API came across the following exception:

**com.ibm.as400.access.AS400SecurityException: Password is expired.**

Does JTOpen provide any method to expire a user's password?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it means the AS400 user's password is expired

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear! I know the meaning of the exception. I'm 99% sure that the password was expired server side. Through this question, I'm trying to be 100% sure, and that there is no possible way to expire a password client side.

Comment: there is no way to expire it on the client side

Comment: Does anyone have a different opinion?